# tidyr::expand_grid() not behaving as expected; what am I missing?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

Here's my reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)

# make some data
a = tibble(b=1:2,c=2:1)
print(a)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       b     c
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     1

expand_grid(a) # doesn't produce the expected output
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       b     c
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     1

# expected output achieved by:
(
    a
    %>% as.list()
    %>% map(unique)
    %>% cross_df()
) 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       b     c
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     2
#> 3     1     1
#> 4     2     1
Created on 2021-08-17 by the reprex package (v2.0.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a different behavior compared to `expand.grid` from `base R`.  But, the behavior is similar if we use `do.call` (or the similar one from `purrr` i.e. `invoke` - retired or `exec` )

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
invoke(expand_grid, a)
exec(expand_grid, !!! a) # from @Mike Lawrence comments
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
      b     c
  <int> <int>
1     1     2
2     1     1
3     2     2
4     2     1
```

i.e. basically, `expand.grid` can work on `list` directly

```
expand.grid(a)
expand.grid(unclass(a))
```

whereas it is different behavior

```
 expand_grid(unclass(a))
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  `unclass(a)`
  <named list>
1 <int [2]>   
2 <int [2]>
```

Comment: Ah, interesting! And I guess invoke is retired, so the current approach would be `exec(expand_grid,!!!a)`

Comment: @MikeLawrence I like the `invoke` option as the `!!!` can be sometimes buggy